# Validation data for multi output Neural network (KERAS)?

Tags: python, validation, keras, scikit-learn, conv-neural-network

I have this kind of model:

[image]

it is a multi-output neural network which I'm struggling with for what concern the validation data.
I'm using the sklearn function "train_test_split":

```
X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val, Z_train, Z_val = train_test_split(rst_src_train, ls_filters_train, sf_train,test_size=0.33,random_state=7)
```

the losse is the mean squared error for both the output layers, but then when i fit the network:

```
model.fit(X_train, [Y_train, Z_train], validation_data=(X_val, Y_val, Z_val), epochs=200)
```

I encounter this error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 40000 and 128 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](2_out_model/sf_vec/BiasAdd, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,40000], [?,128].
```

and I think it's weird because when I do the training without validation data everything works well, any ideas? :)

dimensions are these ones:

```
X_train: (744, 64, 101, 1)
Y_train: (744, 128)
Z_train: (744, 40000)
X_val: (367, 64, 101, 1)
Y_val: (367, 128)
Z_val: (367, 40000)
```

EDIT: here is the model:

```
def get_model():
epochs = 100
learning_rate = 0.1
decay_rate = learning_rate / epochs

inp = keras.Input(shape=(64, 101, 1), name="RST_inputs")
x = layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(3, 3), padding="same")(inp)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(3, 3), padding="same")(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
x = layers.Dense(150)(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
x = layers.Dense(150)(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
out1 = layers.Dense(40000, name="sf_vec")(x)
out2 = layers.Dense(128, name="ls_weights")(x)

model = keras.Model(inp, [out1, out2], name="2_out_model")

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=decay_rate),  # in caso rimettere 0.001
              loss="mean_squared_error")

# keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
model.summary()

return model
```

Comment: I think you need to pass the validation data properly... it's validation_data=(X_val, [Y_val, Z_val]). you need to put your targets inside squared brackets like for training data

Comment: Oh you again! Ahahah thank you for your answer, I've already done that, but the problem remains :/

Comment: is it a problem to report how you build your model? thanks

Comment: I've added the model

Comment: I think you invert Y_val with  Z_val... out1 is 40000 but Y_val is 128 (the contrary for out2 and Z_val)

Comment: You're right...I go crazy when the errors are so trivial, thank you so much! Ahahah